# Integral alternative to $\text{Ei}(x)$ function.

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

Is there an alternative but simple way to find the integral of the following function.
I tried to find  by the method of "Integration by parts" but it again and again result the answer same as question
$$\int (1/x)(e^{5x/2})dx$$

Comment: *erfi(x)*  ??? Sure about it ?

Comment: Do you mean $\text{Ei}(x)$???